# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, migration

I have errors, and I don't know how to work correctly with Eloquent relationships :c
The category number is taken correctly, but user id is wrong. I think that it is taken from the table `models`.`id` but need `models`.`user_id`
Here are my tables:

**photoset_categories** (*catalog with photoset types, ex:* `id = 1, name = 'Studio'; id = 2, name = 'Portrait'`)

```php
Schema::create('photoset_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->comment('Category name');
});
```

**models** (*Model data: eye color, height, weight, etc.*)

```php
Schema::create('models', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->comment('Model id from users');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); // Foreign key

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**model_photosets** (*In which photo shoots the model is photographed*)

```php
Schema::create('model_photosets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('model_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('model_id')->references('user_id')->on('models')->onDelete('cascade'); // Foreign key
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('photoset_categories')->onDelete('cascade'); // Foreign key
});
```

Here are DB Models:

```php
class PhotosetCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'photoset_categories';
    protected $guarded = ['name'];

    public function modelPhotoset()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models');
    }
}
```

...

```php
class Models extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'models';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'd_birth', 'birth', 'm_birth', 'y_birth', 'hair_color', 'eyes_color', 'growth', 'weight'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];


    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function photosets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PhotosetCategory', 'model_photosets', 'model_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

...

```php
class ModelPhotoset extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'model_photosets';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'category_id'];
}
```

**Controller ModelsController**

```php
class ModelsController extends Controller
{
    public function editData(Request $request)
    {
        $title = 'Model data';

        $data = Models::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

        $all_types = PhotosetCategory::all(); // List of photo shoot catagories

        if ($request->has('save')) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                // ...
            ]);

            // UPDATE USER PRO SHOOTS DATA
            $data->photosets()->sync($request->get('ps_types'));
        }

        return view('model.edit', [
            'title' => $title,
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }
}
```

ERROR:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`delavour`.`model_photosets`, CONSTRAINT
>   `model_photosets_model_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`) REFERENCES
>   `models` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into
>   `model_photosets` (`category_id`, `model_id`) values (2, 2))

Answer (score 0):

Error shows that you are trying to insert into model_photosets with model_id 2, but record in models with id 2 doest not exits.

Comment: I know. "2" - field `id` in models table. But I need to get field `user_id` :c
screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8BExJ-ydlwLUVVBM3BkYk5LOFk